# Can't login by using ClaimID

Tags: support, login

Currently I'm not able to login into SO by using ClaimID.

The problem is that i will be forwarded to ClaimID and they are also tell me, that i'm successfully logged into ClaimID with my user credentials. But from there I won't be forwarded to SO again.

Even if i manually switch back to SO I'm not logged into it. Unfortunately i don't have any saved credentials anymore in my browser (hence i wouldn't run into this problem). I also already sent a mail to ClaimID support but didn't get back any answer till now.

Currently i just created a new account to simply ask this question but i would be glad if i could get my old account back to work by pairing it with my new StackExchange login somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No i'm back again as myself. ;-)

Till now the ClaimID still doesn't work to login.

But i created a new OpenID account at StackExchange and used the same mail address as within my profile within SO. Seems that on some magically way (thanks to the StackExchange team for their great work), my two accounts got merged and i'm not a split-ed personality any more.

Comment: A bit late, but I noticed ClaimID failed quite terribly and broke all logins. Probably some key change or something.

Comment: This work-around does not work for Careers 2.0. You must log into StackOverflow first with the new OpenID account and afterwards you'll be able to use the new OpenID in Careers too.