# Is there a problem with the certificate of productivity.stackexchange?

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t login by using ClaimID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156196/cant-login-by-using-claimid)

I get a certificate error when I try to login today.

I see that there are other questions on a similar topic, but they appear to be older. This looks like a new problem.

When I press the login button on this screen:

[image]

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to use `https://` to access the site? That's not supported.

Comment: I am pressing the login button on this page http://productivity.stackexchange.com/users/login

Comment: Which button? You need to be more explicit, there are several there. Can you give us the actual error?

Comment: The "Log in" button, it points to this link: http://productivity.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate

Comment: Oh hey, claimid. I've seen *that* around a few times lately...

Comment: Perhaps claimid redirects back to a https url instead of the correct http url.

Comment: @ShirazBhaiji Are you able to login using CLAIMID now? I contacted them and they said they believe the issue has been resolved. It looks like the certificates have been setup correctly now but I dont have a claimid to test with.

Comment: @droid, thanks for the help. My browser refreshed and I got a "wellcome back" without having to log in. Claimid still has a problem, the name on the certificate does not match the url. You can see it if you go to this address: https://openid.claimid.com/login the cert is for claimid.com, the address is openid.claimid.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, theres no problem with any Stack Exchange certificates. The problem is Clamid's. You can recreate the issue by hitting their [login site directly as well](https://openid.claimid.com/login).

[image]

Im no SSL expert, but it doesnt look like they have a wildcard SSL certificate, namely it looks like their certificate is only good for claimid.com and not for openid.claimid.com. This appears to be a recent change, as [they moved from claimid.com to openid.claimid.com before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11558/did-something-happen-to-the-login-process-on-so-possibly-just-for-claim-id-acco) and now it seems they are reverting (or simply messed up their certificate setup).

According to the certificate dates, it looks like they requested a new certificate (or a renewal) last Friday (11/16/2011). That is, in all likelihood, when the issues began.